# azure ADF - Get field list of .csv file from lookup activity

Tags: csv, azure-data-factory

context: azure - ADF  brief process description:

Get a list of the fields defined in the first row of a .csv(blobed) file. This is the first step, detect fields

then 2nd step would be a kind of compare with actual columns of an SQL table

3rd one a stored procedure execution to make the alter table task, finishing with a (customized) table containing all fields needed to successfully load the .csv file into the SQl table.

To begin my ADF pipeline, I set up a lookup activity that "querys" the first line of my blobed file, `"First row only" flag = ON`.As a second pipeline activity, an "Append Variable" task, there I would like to get all .csv fields(first row) retrieved from the lookup activity, as a list.

Here is where a getting the nightmare.

As far I know, with dynamic content I can get an array with all values (w/ format like `{"field1_name":"field1_value_1st_row", "field2_name":"field2_value_1st_row", etc }`) 
with something like `@activity('Lookup1').output.firstrow`. 
Or any array element with `@activity('Lookup1').output.firstrow.<element_name>`, 
but I can't figure out how to get a list of all field names (keys?) of the array.

I will appreciate any advice, many thanks!

Comment: Hi Jay, first of all, many thanks to take the time to read, and make the effort in understanding this help request. 
Your response is very useful to get picture about que right way to go for. So, if your proposal is to go for azure functions activity, I assume that ADF has no chance to make anything for me natively, (when I was initially writing this question, that was one of my doubts.) Keeping in mind your suggestion I added a python function activity, consuming the lookup activity output. Now I'm struggling with the proper build of the JObject the function must return to ADF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would save the part of LookUp Activity because it seems that you are familiar with it.

You could use Azure Function HttpTrigger to get the key list of firstrow JSON object. For example your json object like this as you mentioned in your question:

```
{"field1_name":"field1_value_1st_row", "field2_name":"field2_value_1st_row"}
```

Azure Function code:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    var array = [];
    for(var key in req.body){
        array.push(key);       
    }
    context.res = {
        body: {"keyValue":array}
    };
};
```

Test Output:

[image]

Then use [Azure Function Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity) to get the output:

```
@activity('<AzureFunctionActivityName>').keyValue
```

Use [Foreach Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity) to loop the keyValue array:

```
@item()
```

---

Still based on the above sample input data,please refer to my sample code:

```
dct = {"field1_name": "field1_value_1st_row", "field2_name": "field2_value_1st_row"}
list = []
for key in dct.keys():
    list.append(key)

print(list)
dicOutput = {"keys": list}
print(dicOutput)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jay, as I mentioned above, my python activity code outputs a list like `(field1_name, field2_name, field3_name...)`, ADF only accepts **JObjects** (lists of dictionaries?') like
`{
    "items": [{
        "name": "adam"
    }, {
        "name": "tom"
    }]`
}
} Any suggestion in how can I get that format, building it from the list (list of fields names) and constant (the key). I tried dict, ObjDict with no results.
Many thanks again.

Comment: Hi Jay, i was trying my own code, I think that I discovered all the ways of ADF JObjects failure errors. Then your code, simply awesome! Exits with OK, .csv field list was received in ADF side, so  I'm back in the pipeline. This is really a milesotne! . Now building the rest of the pipeline. I hove no words to  thank you.

Comment: @manuk You're so so kind... well,if you don't mind,would you please accept this answer(the hook beside answer) which is beneficial for others' reference on the forum?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing this in ADF data flow? You would map the incoming fields to a SQL dataset without a target schema. Define a new table name in the dataset definition and then map the incoming fields from your CSV to a new target table schema definition. ADF will write the rows to a new table using that file's schema.

Comment: HI Mark, many thanks for your comment. it´s a very good suggestion, but I would like to keep the budget as small as possible, I understand that ADF Data flow implies some additional costs. In the other hand, this ADF pipeline will load **lots** (hundreds p/day) of (blobbed) .csv files with (posibly) some variations in its column structures, if I got  your suggestion (right), I would end with a **new table** per .csv file ***load-iteration***.This ADF pipeline iterates per .csv file due constraints related with the heterogeneous table structure. Each .csv file must be loaded in a unique table.

Comment: It's your choice. You can ask ADF to generate a new table per CSV or you can load into a pre-existing table.